# How can I load data in combo item property when another changed, in propertygrid c#?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have two property in my class: **MyCountry** & **MyCity**. I set this class to sourceobject of a property grid. I want load cities i combo when select a country. for example I have 2 Country data:

```
Country1
Country2
```

And For Country1, I have (city data)

```
City11
City12
City13
```

And For Country2, I have (city data)

```
city21
City22
City23
```

When I change select country item in propertygrid, I want load cities of it in city item. this mean, when select **Country1**, display **City11,City12,City13** in City item and when select **Country2** Display **City21,Cityy22,City23** in City Item.

How can I It ?

my class is :

```
public class KeywordProperties
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CountryLocationConvertor))]
    public string MyCountry { get; set; }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CityLocationConvertor))]
    public string MyCity { get; set; }
}
```

and I use below class for load countries data for display in combo :

```
public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {            
        HumanRoles Db = new HumanRoles();
        List<LocationsFieldSet> Items = new List<LocationsFieldSet>();
        Items = Db.LoadLocations(0);
        string[] LocationItems = new string[Items.Count];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (LocationsFieldSet Item in Items)
        {
            LocationItems[count] = Item.Title;
            count++;
        }
        return new StandardValuesCollection(LocationItems);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ITypeDescriptorContext` interface provides a property called `Instance`
which lets you access the object to which the type descriptor request is connected.

You can use this property to determine the current value of the `MyCountry` property
the user selected. Depending on the value you can load the cities for this country.

Furthermore, in the setter of the `MyCountry` property I check whether or not the
new value is different from the old one and if this is the case I reset the `MyCity` property
(to not get an invalid combination of country and city).

Here is a small code sample. For the sake of simplicity I only use one type converter
for both properties.

```
public class KeywordProperties
{    
  public KeywordProperties()
  {
    MyCountry = "Country1";
  }

  private string myCountry;
  [TypeConverter(typeof(ObjectNameConverter))]
  public string MyCountry
  {
    get { return myCountry; }
    set 
    {
      if (value != myCountry)
        MyCity = "";

      myCountry = value; 
    }
  }

  private string myCity;
  [TypeConverter(typeof(ObjectNameConverter))]
  public string MyCity
  {
    get { return myCity; }
    set { myCity = value; }
  }   
}

public class ObjectNameConverter : StringConverter
{
  public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
    KeywordProperties myKeywordProps = context.Instance as KeywordProperties;

    if (context.PropertyDescriptor.Name == "MyCountry")
    {
      List<string> listOfCountries = new List<string>();
      listOfCountries.Add("Country1");
      listOfCountries.Add("Country2");        

      return new StandardValuesCollection(listOfCountries);
    }      

    List<string> listOfCities = new List<string>();
    if (myKeywordProps.MyCountry == "Country1")
    {
      listOfCities.Add("City11");
      listOfCities.Add("City12");
      listOfCities.Add("City13");
    }
    else
    {
      listOfCities.Add("City21");
      listOfCities.Add("City22");
      listOfCities.Add("City23");
    }

    return new StandardValuesCollection(listOfCities);
  }
}
```

In the example above there is one side effect I do not like.
Setting the `MyCountry` property leads to settting also the `MyCity` property.

To workaround this side effect you could also use the `PropertyValueChanged` event
of the `PropertyGrid` to handle invalid country/city selections.

```
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ChangedItem.Label == "MyCountry")
  {
    if(e.ChangedItem.Value != e.OldValue)
      m.MyCity = "";
  }
}
```

If you use this event, just repalce the code in the setter of the `MyCountry` property with:

```
myCountry = value;
```